# change fab.onclicklistener to intent

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent, gridview

i have problem on change fab button click to intent
this is my AlatActivity.java

```
public class AlatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String urlAddress="https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/getAlat.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alat_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final GridView gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloaderAlat(AlatActivity.this,urlAddress ,gv).execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my intent in

```
 ImageView favBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favBtn);
        favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlatActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

and this is my DownloaderAlat.Java

```
public class DownloaderAlat extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    GridView gv;

    ProgressDialog pd;

    public DownloaderAlat(Context c, String urlAddress, GridView gv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
        this.gv = gv;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Loading Data Alat");
        pd.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu....");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return this.downloadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String jsonData){
        super.onPostExecute(jsonData);
        pd.dismiss();

        if (jsonData==null){
            Toast.makeText(c,"gagal load data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            ParserAlat parserAlat= new ParserAlat(c, jsonData,gv);
            parserAlat.execute();
        }
    }

    private String downloadData(){
        HttpURLConnection con= KonektorAlat.connect(urlAddress);
        if(con==null){
            return null;
        }
        try {
            InputStream is= new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            StringBuffer jsonData= new StringBuffer();

            while ((line=br.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                jsonData.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();
            is.close();
            return jsonData.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

i want to show my gridview without click fab button,,,
because when i remove fab.setonclicklistener function,,,
my project error: cannot convert cardview into gridview,,
how i can get my data in downloaderAlat.java without click fab button?

okay this is my alat_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AlatActivity"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_alat"/>
    
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email">

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my content_alat.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AlatActivity"
    >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="2"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood your question, you want to make the network call without having to click on the Fab button.

```
public class AlatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
static String urlAddress="https://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/getAlat.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alat_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GridView gv= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);

    new DownloaderAlat(AlatActivity.this,urlAddress ,gv).execute();
}
}
```

Try replacing the above code in your `AlatActivity.class`

Change your Layout file to below code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AlatActivity"
    >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        ></GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: okay,,, my purpose is downloading data from mysql without clik fab button, so when i click my intent button it with automatically read data from mysql and show in gridview, i will try your suggestion.. thanks for your answer sir.

Comment: this is my error when i try to remove fab.setonclicklistener

Comment: Yes, so when your `AlatActivity` opens, onCreate method will be called and the GridView will be populated from the `new DownloaderAlat AsyncTask`

Comment: this is my logchat,      android.support.v7.widget.CardView cannot be cast to android.widget.GridView at baru.azoel.ayomuncak.AlatActivity.onCreate(AlatActivity.java:21)

Comment: Can you update the question and add your layout file - `alat_main`

Comment: Why are you using a `CardView` inside your Layout and using `GridView` inside your Activity?

Comment: Either change the Layout to `GridView`, or the change the Activity code to `CardView`

Comment: I've updated the answer, make the changes accordingly.

Comment: I'm frustrated in my code because i'm following tutorial in youtube and i'm newbie in android programming,,,are you have link preferred that explain about gridview and detail item that data from mysql?thanks sir from your answer

Comment: the Layout file, You can learn more about GridViews from this tutorial - [Android Hive](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

Comment: Check the answer above.